# Error in SQL syntax when casting a column from int to varchar(32)?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, casting

So, I want to cast a column from int to varchar(32) as you can see below

```
SELECT CAST(`numbertwo` AS VARCHAR(32)) FROM `tablee`
```

But when entering the query, it reports, that I have an error in my SQL syntax.
Can you help me how I can fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL wants `CHAR` instead:

```
SELECT CAST(`numbertwo` AS CHAR) FROM `tablee`
```

You can specify a target length, in which case values that are too long are truncated (but no padding occurs for shorter values):

```
SELECT CAST(`numbertwo` AS CHAR(32)) FROM `tablee`
```

Reference: [MySQL's `CONVERT()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)